# Detecting new line in HTML textarea

Tags: php, html, textarea

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Newline Conversion in Submitted Text in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454732/newline-conversion-in-submitted-text-in-php)

I'm using PHP to store text submitted from a textarea into a database to later be echoed out. If a user presses enter in the textbox to start a new line, I want it to start a line break.

How can I go about doing that?

Let's say this is the textbox:

```
This is line one.
This is line two.
```

When a user submits this to the database it is just stored as one line and echoed out is the same result.
"This is line one. This is line two."

So how do I make the stored text reflect the format of the original input?

Comment: what do you mean `I want it to start a line break`?

Comment: you can replace all `\n` with `</br>`: `str_replace("\n","<br />",$string);  GO to the 1st link
`

Comment: Make sure you use "\n" and not '\n'!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You would run something like nl2br() on your output when reading FROM the database. The new lines will be stored as \n.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.nl2br.php

It should also be noted that you should not run nl2br() before inserting into the database. Just not a good practice.

Comment: I edited the question to clarify. Is this still applicable?

Comment: Yes. I would suggest trying it out though. No harm in testing.